# Getting loads of error when using NSOpenPanel

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, nsopenpanel

I found this code online, which is supposed to open an open dialog in C++. But I'm getting loads of errors. This is the code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <string>

std::string* path() {
    NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    if ([op runModal] == NSOKButton) {
        NSURL *nsurl = [[op URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
            std::string([[nsurl path] UTF8String]);
    }
    //Here i do stuff with the string.
    return something;
}
```

Here is a list of the errors I'm getting in Xcode: 
http://gyazo.com/5b2b5da1d5eca9dd9d6f53eec438850e

Thanks.

Comment: That is Objective-C++, not C++. Your file should have the ".mm" extension. (Also, don't post links to screenshots - almost nobody will look at them and they expire, making the question meaningless.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your project is linking in the required framework.

Under the settings for the build target, under the "General" tab, scroll to the bottom and find the section "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". You should see `Cocoa.framework` listed. If you do not, click the plus sign at the bottom, search for "cocoa" in the popup dialog, and add `Cocoa.framework`.